# Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'Window'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this simple code in my index.tsx

```
let state = {};

window.setState = (changes: any) => {
       state = Object.assign({}, state, changes);

 ReactDOM.render(<App {...state} />, document.getElementById("root"));
};
```

but i get the error as

> Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'Window'.

in my Dependencies i have the following

```
"dependencies": {
"@types/react": "^16.7.7",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
}
```

I am following this [React Auth](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-auth0-el6bzg?file=index.js)

Comment: It should be this.setState but not window.setState I think

Comment: @HemadriDasari okay, let me try and get back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To those saying it should be `this.setState()`, I don't think it should. It's just unfortunate that the example given by that React Auth library is defining a weird and poorly named (in the context of React) global function called `setState()`.

This is the example JavaScript given in your link:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

let state = {};
window.setState = changes => {
    state = Object.assign({}, state, changes);

    ReactDOM.render(<App {...state} />, document.getElementById("root"));
};

/* eslint no-restricted-globals: 0*/

let initialState = {
    isLoggedIn: false,
    signup: function () {
        window.open(
            "https://auth0.com/signup?utm_source=stackblitz&utm_medium=devsponsor&utm_campaign=stackblitz-react",
            "_blank"
        );
    }
};

window.setState(initialState);
```

You just need to extend `window` to keep TypeScript happy:

```
declare global {
    interface Window {
        setState: (changes: any) => void;
    }
}

let state = {};

window.setState = (changes: any) => {
    state = Object.assign({}, state, changes);
};
```

Although it looks like a bad implementation unless I'm missing something. You should be using React's state (and/or something like Redux) rather than re-rendering the app when one of these properties changes.

Comment: hey awesome..i had declared the paramater 'changes' to any type but unforturnaly i was not realising the 'window' DOM. Typescript types can be a pain at times :P thanks a lot man. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think it shouldn't be `window.setstate`, it should be `this.setstate({})`